# Eagerload has_one association with a table that has multiple related values

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So I have the following models defined:

```
class Album
  has_many :photos
  has_one :cover_photo, class_name: "Photo"
end

class Photo
  belongs_to :photo
end
```

What I want to do now is eagerload the `cover_photo` association when loading albums like this:

`Album.where(...).includes(:cover_photo)`

But according to ActiveRecord documentation and the observed behavior, `limit` (which is what the `has_one` association is defining), is not respected. So I get the following query:

```
Photo Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."album_id" IN (5, 4, 2, 1)
```

Although, `album.cover_photo` now returns a single object without firing extra queries, clearly ALL photos are being loaded from the database which is not what I want here.

I know I can achieve this with using a JOIN and have access to the photo attributes inside the album object, but I really need to be able to use the `Photo` model as the knowledge of interpreting the photo attributes lives in there.

Comment: If the query had a limit, wouldn't it break preloading if you were loading more than one album?

Let's say you had 5 albums, and each of them had a cover photo.

If the preloading query had a `LIMIT 1`, then the last 4 albums wouldn't get their `cover_photo` loaded, because the query was limited to return a single row (unless they had the same `cover_photo`).

Comment: @kaspernj yes, that's why ActiveRecord strips the `LIMIT` clause and just pulls all photos records from the database but exposes only one of them through the `Album#cover_photo` API. But its a memory waste

Answer (score 0):

This article answers my question exactly and also another question I had regarding how I can manually preload records into an AR association - https://mrbrdo.wordpress.com/2013/09/25/manually-preloading-associations-in-rails-using-custom-scopessql/

Relevant code from the post:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
  has_one :display_photo, -> {
    self.select_values = ["DISTINCT ON(photos.album_id) photos.*"]
    order('photos.album_id')
    }, class_name: "Photo"
end
```